# Failed to Find Any Kerberos TGT while trying to access Kerberized HBase Without kinit

Tags: hbase, kerberos, cloudera, jaas, keytab

I have a very simple Scala HBase GET application.
I tried to make the connection as below:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.{HBaseConfiguration, TableName}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.{ConnectionFactory, Get}

object Debug extends App {
    val hbaseConf: HadoopConf = HBaseConfiguration.create
    val connection: Connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(hbaseConf)
    val hbaseTable = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf("my-hbase-table"))
    hbaseTable.get(new Get("rowkey".getBytes).addColumn("colFam".getBytes,"colName".getBytes))
}
```

Whenever I run this, I get an error like below:

```
Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:211)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.AbstractHBaseSaslRpcClient.getInitialResponse(AbstractHBaseSaslRpcClient.java:131)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.NettyHBaseSaslRpcClientHandler$1.run(NettyHBaseSaslRpcClientHandler.java:108)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.NettyHBaseSaslRpcClientHandler$1.run(NettyHBaseSaslRpcClientHandler.java:104)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1746)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.NettyHBaseSaslRpcClientHandler.handlerAdded(NettyHBaseSaslRpcClientHandler.java:104)
at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAdded0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:606)
at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.addFirst(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:187)
at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.addFirst(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:380)
at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.addFirst(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:359)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcConnection.saslNegotiate(NettyRpcConnection.java:200)
... 18 more
Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:162)
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:122)
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:189)
at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:224)
at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:212)
at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:192)
... 30 more
```

I am using Windows, so I have put 4 files under the root directory of C: drive:

```
    C:\cacerts
    C:\jaas.conf
    C:\krb5.conf
    C:\principal.keytab
```

My C:\jaas.conf :

```
KafkaClient {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    useKeyTab=true
    keyTab="C:\\principal.keytab"
    useTicketCache=false
    debug=true
    principal="principal@REALM";
};
Client {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    useKeyTab=true
    keyTab="C:\\principal.keytab"
    useTicketCache=false
    debug=true
    principal="principal@REALM";
};
com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.initiate {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    useKeyTab=true
    keyTab="C:\\principal.keytab"
    principal="principal@REALM";
};
```

I am on Cloudera CDH version 6.3.2. Downloaded hbase-client-config (ssl-client.xml, hdfs-site.xml, hbase-site.xml, core-site.xml) from Cloudera manager and added HBase client config files under resources folder in IntelliJ. [my-hbase-client-config-files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATGN3.png)

And also set VM options for `jaas.conf` in IntelliJ, Run/Debug Configurations -> Application -> Build and run -> VM Options. [my-intellij-application-vm-options-config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYtNJ.png)

When application is started, am able to see `jaas.conf` file is being taken [jaas.conf-logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikl41.png)

Even if it is saying that it gonna use the keytab, still I am getting error like this: [Kerberos-error-message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qfbe.png)

My Cloudera version: 6.3.2

Scala version: 2.11.12

HBase Client: 2.1.0

Does anyone has any ideas?
Is Java authentication system not taking Kerberos ticket by itself when I give jaas.conf?

Comment: I do not need to see the actual 'principal@REALM' is but can you confirm that it's not in the format: 'principal/www.domain.com@REALM' which would denote it's bound to a server?

Comment: I am using it like principal@REALM not like principal/www.domain.com@REALM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if HBase client implements Service Provider Interface (which would enable the use of JAAS-style security config).

Perhaps you can try to add UGI initialization in your Scala code directly, like below?

```
object Debug extends App {
   val hbaseConf: HadoopConf = HBaseConfiguration.create

   UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(hbaseConf)
   UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("principal@REALM","C:\\principal.keytab")

   val connection: Connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(hbaseConf)
   :
   etc
   :
```

Otherwise, could you share a reference/link to any information that suggests that it is configurable thru `jaas.conf`?

Comment: Hello, it seems you are right. Because i couldn't find documentation for HBase clients authenticating through jaas.conf, but i assumed i could use it. We have several KafkaClients, and they are being authenticated using jaas.conf. :/

I solved it as you suggested. 
`UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(hbaseConf)`
`UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("principal@REALM","C:\\principal.keytab")`
`val ugi =UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI(principal,keytab)`
`new Thread( new Runnable{ override def run() = {while(true){ ugi.checkTGTAndReloginFromKeytab() }}} ).start`

Comment: Cool, thanks! One other alternative, if you'd like to keep you code "clean" could be to use k5start (https://linux.die.net/man/1/k5start). But... stop, you're on Windows right? Why? ;)

Comment: No, i am developing the application on windows, but deploying it on kubernetes.

Comment: Indeed, I didnt want to put kerberos and principal inside of the code to keep it clean.

Comment: Then perhaps you can take a closer look at k5start, because of its power to combine kinit + tgt renewal, all right from command-line.

Comment: I want to remove any kerberos related parts from my code, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will get this error message when Jaas cannot access the kerberos keytab.

Can you check for user permission issues?
Login as user that will run the code and do a kinit ?  What error message do you get? (Resolve the permission issue I'm suggesting you  have.)

You seem to rule out a path issue, and seem to have the correct '\\'.

Comment: The principal@REALM belongs to the service user.
E.g: my user: A, service user: B. And principal is B@REALM. 
I am trying to reach to kerberized HBase with service user's principal. Service user principal has enough permissions to access HBase.

When i call `kinit -k -t B@REALM`, am able to run this code (with user A), all is fine.
I am already using double backslash `keyTab="C:\\principal.keytab"`

Comment: I'm sorry I think you either did not understand.my response or didn't communicate your understanding. This is a file permission issue. Reread my response. It's clear there is a misunderstanding as I commented you *had* handled the "\\\\" issue. So please take some time to consider the user running this application does not have permission to access the keytab file.

Comment: It's reading jaas.conf file indeed.  Here is application logs:  
`Debug is true storeKey true useTicketCache true useKeyTab true doNotPrompt true ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab ... `
 `Acquire TGT from Cache `
 `Principal is principal@REALM `
 `null credentials from Ticket Cache `
 `principal is principal@REALM `
 `Will use keytab `
 `Commit Succeeded`

Comment: Am able to call kinit with the same keytab. When i call kinit `kinit -k -t principal.keytab principal@REALM`, my application is reaching to kerberized HBase and applcation is ending succesfully. But when I give `-Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:\jaas.conf` without calling `kinit`, shouldn't the app call `kinit` by itself?

Comment: useTicketCache true -> this means that you will use existing kinit.  (And this isdifferent than the setting you posted.)
Also I have asked for this a could times but it's still not clear.  Did you use the App user to complete the kinit?  It's not clear from your comments that you completed this step as I requested.

Comment: I was trying lots of things, it probably stayed as `useTicketCache=true`.
But its also not working while `useTicketCache=false` (as i posted). the problem is that when i manually call `kinit -k -t principal.keytab principal@REALM` there is not any problem in the application. The user `principal` is a service user (which is different than my user) and I am able to call `kinit` for service user on my local environment. I can't access kerberized hbase service when there are no valid ticket cache even if i give the configs. (like in the post.)

Comment: @gurbux - I'm sorry, you aren't clearly communicating what i have asked.  And I'm sorry it's getting frustrating. What user is running the application?  Your user?  a service account?

Comment: My local windows user is running the app and i am giving service user's principal and keytab in the jaas.conf. Hope its clear now